# Local runtime on Google Colab detects only half of installed RAM?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, ram

I noticed that when I connect to local runtime on Google Colab, it shows that I am using 4.8 / 15.5 GB of system RAM and 62.4 / 1006.9 GB of Disk space under my Resources tab.

My computer has 2 sticks of 16 GB RAM, a 1TB SSD and a 4070 Ti as GPU. All of these are correctly detected by my Windows system.

I assume the 15.5 GB of RAM is because Colab is only detecting one of the 2 RAM sticks installed on my device? Am I looking at this right? What can I do to ensure that I have access to all 32 GB of system RAM?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: No software entity in your system has any clue how many RAM sticks you have.  The Google Colab server is running on a completely different computer in a different city from your machine.  It doesn't know anything about YOUR computer.  You have been assigned 1TB of their disk space.  The fact that it matches your disk size is a coincidence.

Comment: Oh, I see. So does that mean even though I'm on local runtime, I'm still bound to using Colab server's RAM & Disk space, and the only true local resource I can bring into the session is my GPU?

Comment: Right.  That's why sharing works -- your scripts and data live on their servers.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I'm still learning so I appreciate the explanation

Comment: @TimRoberts I thought the OP was talking a [local Colab Runtime](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) (as far as I get, either running a local Docker image or jupyer notebook that Google Colab connects to (via websockets + port forwarding). I might be wrong, but I'm interested in understanding more abou this.

Comment: @ojw92 How are seeing the RAM resources in the Resources tab ? Maybe I'm missing something, but I just tried connecting with a Colab Pro and I get this message:: "You are not subscribed." (with the resource plots being empty). using the `psutil` python module I could see my machine's username in the Colab Notebook via `psutil.os.getlogin()` and I could see full RAM via `psutil.virtual_memory()`. Have you entered an url like `http://localhost:8888/?token=YOUR_JUPYTER_TOKEN` in Colab (via "Connect to a local runtime" ?